# How to check if $\phi(n)$ is a perfect square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> How to check if $\phi(n)$ is a perfect square?

Here, $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.  That is,$\phi(n)$ counts the positive integers up to a given integer $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$

for example if $n = 34$, $\phi(34)=16=4\times 4$.

Can we check this without calculating $\phi(n)$?

Comment: Probably not.  I think you need to know which prime $p$ divides $\phi(n)$.  While this doesn't mean you have to calculate $\phi(n)$, it means you need to know the prime factorization of $n$.  That is basically almost calculating $\phi(n)$ itself.   While you don't need to know how many times $p$ divides $\phi(n)$, you need to know if it divides $\phi(n)$ with an even exponent.  That is not very far away from calculating $\phi(n)$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$ If $n \in \N$ has prime factorization $n = \prod p_i^{m_i}$, the Chinese remainder theorem implies that $\phi(n) = \prod \phi(p_i^{m_i}) = \prod p_i^{m_i - 1} (p_i - 1)$. You can apply the idea of the sieve of Eratosthenes to this formula. That is, you can compute the parity of each $m_i$ for increasing $n \in \N$. Of course there may be more clever methods.

Comment: I agree Batominovski. Strictly speaking we can argue that we can derive the result from the prime factorization, but if we have the factorization, we basically also have $\varphi(n)$. If we do not know the prime factors, we cannot decide whether $\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Maybe , the sequence "numbers $n$ for which $\varphi(n)$ is a perfect square" is something for OEIS, if it is not already present there.

Comment: Re Peter: Yes, it is present in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A039770).